# Computing line integrals: $\gamma_3(t)=4\exp(it)$ $\int_{\gamma_3}f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z+1}+\frac{1}{z-1}$$

$$\gamma_j:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{C} \ (j=1,2,3)$$

\begin{align}
\gamma_j(t) & =(-1)^j+\frac{1}{2}\exp(it) \text{ for } j=1,2 \\[10pt]
\gamma_3(t) & =4\exp(it)
\end{align}

I need  to compute

$$\int_{\gamma_1}f(z)\, \mathrm{d}z + \int_{\gamma_2}f(z) \,\mathrm{d}z \text{ and } \int_{\gamma_3}f(z) \,\mathrm{d}z.$$

Can I compute them using $$\int_\gamma{dz\over z-a}=2\pi i\> n(\gamma,a)$$

And if so, how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

The curve $\gamma_1$ winds once counterclockwise around $-1.$ It's just a circle of radius $1/2.$ So you can apply the equality you state at the end of the question to $\displaystyle \int_{\gamma_1} \frac{dz}{z+1}.$ But you have the other term, $\displaystyle \int_{\gamma_1} \frac{dz}{z-1}.$ Here you need to note that $z\mapsto\dfrac 1 {z-1}$ is holomorphic everywhere in the interior and on the boundary of $\gamma_1.$ There is a theorem dealing with that situation.

As for $\gamma_3,$ have you drawn the circle and observed how it is related to the two points $1$ and $-1\text{?}$

Comment: For the first two integrals, the curves just wind around $-1$ and $1$ once so the solution should be $2 \pi i$ for each integral. But I don't understand why I need to know something about $f$ here? And yes I have drawn it, it winds around $0$ with radius $4$ but I don't know how that helps me. Thanks!

Comment: @user567319 : Have you noticed that both $1$ and $-1$ are inside that circle of radius $4\text{?} \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $f(z)$ has poles at $1$ and $-1$.

You should also know that for a path parametrized as 
$$\gamma(t)=s+re^{it}$$
is a circle of radius $r$ centered at $s$.

Also note that in the formula you stated at the end of your question, $n(\gamma,a)$ is $0$ if $\gamma$ does not contain $a$, else equal $k$ where $k$ is the number of times the path is travelled.

Then one can immediately see $\gamma_1$ contains the pole at $-1$ only and $\gamma_2$ contains the pole at $1$ only.

Thus, you get the answer $2\pi i$ for the first two integrals(conventionally the path is travelled once so $n(\gamma,a)=1$).

$\gamma_3$ contains both poles. But don’t panic.

$$\int_{\gamma_3} f(z) \, dz=\int_{\gamma_3}  \frac1{z+1}\,dz+\int_{\gamma_3}  \frac1{z-1} \, dz$$

Do you now see the answer?

Comment: Ok, so $a$ is the pole? Then $\int_{\gamma_3}f(z)dz=2\pi i + 2\pi i$?

Comment: @user567319 Correct!:)